# No display at https

Tags: google-maps

The map is not displayed at https, the map is displayed at http. my code is the following:

```
<script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=??????????????????&signed_in=true&callback=initMap;language=???"></script>
```

There are no restrictions in Google Map platform!
Who helps me?

nothing, don't know what to do next

Comment: All the posted code is doing is including the API, just that code won't display a map anywhere.  Please provide a [mcve]